# Coded UI Test without installing Visual Studio

Tags: testing, coded-ui-tests

is there any way to execute a Coded UI Test ->without<- installing VS Premium/Ultimate ->AND<- ->without<- using Microsoft Test Manager. I don't want to execute tests remotely.

The scenario is:

Push a Coded UI Test to a XP machine and execute tests with the help of a WCF Service.

Hope someone can help me.

Lee

PS:

Executing a CUI Test will throw an Exception like this:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Where is the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.dll located?

Answer (score 1):

Tests can be run from the command line with the `mstest.exe` program, but I am not sure what else you would need to install to get it to work without also having Visual Studio or MTM.

Running tests without Visual Studio and without MTM is common, but normally done with a "test agent". Configuring a computer as a test agent is easy (if you have the licences) and described in documents such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd648127.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh546459.aspx . Test agents are normally used for remote execution which is not what you want Installing the agent software allows remote execution and so I would expect it to also provide enough to run your test from `mstest.exe`. I have not tried any of this, so no guarantees!